# If $z,w$ are complex valued and $z^2=w^2$ is $z=w$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to show that the function $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ for $A=\{z:\Re(z)>0\}$ given by $f(z)=Log(z^2+1)$ is univalent.

My proof is as follows.

Choose any $z,w\in A$ and suppose that $Log(z^2+1)=Log(w^2+1)$. Then since we are dealing with the principal log we have

$$
\ln|z^2+1|+iArg(z^2+1)=\ln|w^2+1|+iArg(w^2+1)
$$

so $\ln|z^2+1|=\ln|w^2+1|$ and $Arg(z^2+1)=Arg(w^2+1)$. From $\ln|z^2+1|=\ln|w^2+1|$, we see that after taking the exponential of both sides we get $|z^2+1|=|w^2+1|$. Also since $Arg(z^2+1)=Arg(w^2+1)=\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$ such that $\theta$ satisfies

$$
z^2+1=|z^2+1|(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)\\
w^2+1=|w^2+1|(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta).
$$

Hence $z^2+1=w^2+1$ which gives us $z^2=w^2$.

If $z^2=w^2$ implies that $z=w$ then I am done but I feel like that part needs justification. Does it necessarily follow? If not how can I fix my proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use
$$
z^2+1=\exp(\operatorname{Log}(z^2+1))=\exp(\operatorname{Log}(w^2+1))=w^2+1
$$

$$
z^2=w^2 \Rightarrow z^2-w^2=(z+w)(z-w)=0 \Rightarrow z=w \text{ or } z=-w
$$
and $z=-w$
$$
\mathfrak{R}(z)=\mathfrak{R}(-w)=-\mathfrak{R}(w) < 0
$$
is impossible

Comment: I want to be as thorough as possible with the definition of Log so I am keeping the Args' in there. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

No. $\sqrt[n]x$ returns *n* distinct complex values. So the fact that $z^2=w^2$ simply means that *z* and *w* are among the two distinct complex solutions for $\sqrt x$. But what these values have in common is the fact that $|z|=|w|$, as well as the fact that $n\cdot\arg z$ and $n\cdot\arg w$ are both integer multiples of $2\pi$. In the case of $n=2$, we have the two complex values of $\sqrt x$ lying at the two extremities of a line segment whose center is in $0$, the angle between them being obviously $180^0$, so it would therefore be impossible for both of them to lie in the same half-plane. Ergo, $z=w$, but NOT merely because $z^2=w^2$ !

Comment: But $z$ and $w$ are taken from the set $A$ of complex numbers with positive real part, thus $z^2 = w^2$ implies $z = w$, as shown by the simple argument given by Blah below.

Comment: @heropup: Corrected and expanded.